# Different callOut in annotationView

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, annotations

I am working on Map iOS6, and I got some troubles:
As the images below, the annotation of current location and placeMark also have the callOut button but I need the button do different task, how can I do that? It means that in current location, I need callOut button for this task and in placeMark, the callout button do another task.
Please visit this page to see the image
http://upanh.com/listing/?s=c3f4954854a30fe50e3e15f9ae064ba2
I have not enough reputation to post the image here.
I tried this code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure)
    {
       ...
       locationSheet.cancelButtonIndex = locationSheet.numberOfButtons - 1;
    }else if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeInfoLight)
    {
       ...
       locationSheet.cancelButtonIndex = locationSheet.numberOfButtons - 1;
    }
}
```

and

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // 1
    if (buttonIndex != actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do the different task between two button in actionSheet? It's quite hard to explain my situation, I hope everyone understand what I perform above and I appreciate your helps.
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get to your images - but if you have actual buttons (UIButton) and not MKAnnotations, then why not specify a tag for your buttons (different tag for each, of course), point them at the same function, and then differentiate based on tags? So (this can be used for any button not just `UIButtonTypeCustom`, and for any `UIView` actually - they all support `tag`):

```
 UIButton *firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 UIButton *secondButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

 firstButton.tag = 100;
 secondButton.tag = 200;

 [firstButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething:)];
 [secondButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething:)];

 - (void)doSomething:(id)sender {
 UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

 if (pressedButton.tag == 100) {
 //First button
 }
 else if (pressedButton.tag == 200) {
 //Second button
 }
```

Comment: Well, I did it. I forgot "tag" function. Thanks again Jai Govindani.

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Please accept the answer if it helped you. Cheers!